# Dotnet publish copies appsettings*.json only for Asp.Net (but not Console)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-publish

I am running `dotnet publish` (via VS2019 GUI or a command, same result) on an ASP.Net project and on a Console project.

It seems that behaviour differs. All `appsettings*.json` are being copied automatically in ASP.Net, but on console only if I set them to `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>`.

Is this some kind of a bug or is it really designed to be different depending on project type?

The behavior looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: My guess would be that since the console project type doesn't require the appsettings files (as they are mostly used in ASP.NET Core), they're not copied by default. It does seem a little weird, but it makes sense to me (if my guess turns out to be true)

Comment: Strictly speaking ASP.NET core does not require them either :)

Comment: Huh. I never knew. The more you know, I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you compare the `.csproj` files for both projects, you will notice that the ASP.NET Core project references an SDK `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` while the console project just references `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. The SDK is basically a pre-defined set of configurations and defaults to make working with ASP.NET Core or console applications simple and the project file easy to read and maintain.

The `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` actually extends the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` so everything the latter SDK does is also included in the Web SDK. The Web SDK just adds some more ASP.NET Core related stuff. This also means that a web application is just a console application.

One of the lines the Web SDK contains that are *not* included in the general SDK [is the following](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/release/2.2.2xx/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props#L32):

```
<Content Include="**\*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder);$(DefaultWebContentItemExcludes)" />
```

This basically defines all `.json` files as content that should be copied to the publish directory. So basically this is exactly what makes ASP.NET Core projects copy the `appsettings.json` files to the publish directory.

Since this is not part of the normal project SDK, console applications will not automatically copy `appsettings.json` files to the publish directory. This is generally *intentional* because raw console applications are not necessarily built upon the configuration system that uses these files.

It is *possible* (and it becomes probably more relevant in the future with the generic host in 3.0) but not a default. So if you want to copy the files to the publish directory, then you should add that rule yourself to your `.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Btw. since you mentioned in the comments that ASP.NET Core doesn’t really *require* `appsettings.json` files itself (which is absolutely true), the Web SDK does expose two properties `EnableDefaultItems` and `EnableDefaultContentItems` to disable this default behavior (along with a few others).

Comment: Thanks for the long and comprehensive answer, is there somewhere on github I can find the line you are referring to?

Comment: Btw, what makes launchSettings.json not being copied as well, is there a separate exclude on this one or something?

Comment: Found both answers here: https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/9e0bcbae34d4686e6a545b21c5d3c7862ca54266/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props#L31-L32

Comment: [This is the line](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/release/2.2.2xx/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props#L32) that configures the `.json` files. And [this is the part](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/release/2.2.2xx/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props#L34-L35) that prevents stuff within the `Properties` folder from being copied.

Comment: I have tested what you propose and it actually adds a lot of garbage from Properties, obj, etc. So I did this: Include="appsettings*.json". I guess all the garbage is turned off in asp.net as well.

Comment: Yeah, you’re right, it’s probably better to just use `*.json` to avoid looking in subfolders. You can always add individual files there later if you encounter them, but the usual `appsettings` are probably always in the project root.